# Multiple langues with textView and setText

Tags: android, textview, settext

I use a ImageAdapter to set a custom view with images and a caption. How can I support multiple langues for this text?

The text is now wet in the  getView(...) method in the imageAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_icon, null);

            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.main_icon_text);
            tv.setText("**MENU TEXT**");

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.main_icon_image);

            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        return v;
    }
```

I guess the "MENU TEXT" should be set dynamically from res/Strings to support different langues, but how can I do this?

The GridView has four images that should have four different strings. E.g. "Add friend", "find friend", "Edit friend" and "Delete friend".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to read this training:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Then, your code should look like this:

view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.YOURSTRINGKEY));

Comment: Yes, I get that. The problem is that getView() in the imageAdapter will be called one time for each image, so different strings must be used each time.

Comment: Use an ENUM to define position Strings, and then a Switch(position)

Answer (score 2):

First put the string value in a resource file: res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="menu_text">menu text</string>
```

Then resolve the string at runtime:

```
String menuText = context.getString(R.string.menu_text);
```

Then you can use foreign-language versions of the strings file for translations:
e.g. res/values-fr/strings.xml

Comment: Yes, The problem is that getView is called once for each image. But I can solve this with an if-statement for the "position". Is that the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You will simply use the [TextView.setText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) varient (e.g. R.string.menu_text_hello) and put the [strings into the respected res folders](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Comment: Yes, so I have to use a if-statement with "position"?. I.e. if(position==1) string = getString(R.string.menu1); else if(position == 2) getSTring(R.string.menu_text2) etc..?

Comment: Um, you can use, say int text. and just have setText(text) after your if and elses.